# Templates aren't called in custom module?

Tags: 8

I am trying to add templates for the paragraph in a custom module, but it uses only the *paragraph.html.twig* template file.

*paragraph--example-ch-hero-panel.html.twig* is one of the suggested template files, which is the one I am using.

By default, The template should be taken from the paragraph, but it doesn't work in my case. I didn't implement `hook_theme()` in a module for this because I am not passing any value to the templates.

I tried the following code, but I got an error.

```php
function example_ch_hero_panel_theme() {
  return [
    'paragraph__example_ch_hero_panel' => [
      'render element' => 'element',
      'template' => 'paragraph--example-ch-hero-panel',
      'base hook' => 'paragraph',
    ],
  ];
}

function example_ch_hero_panel_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['page']['path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'example_ch_hero_panel') . '/templates';
}
```

It throws the following  exception.

> Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template "modules/custom/example_ch_hero_panel/templates/page.html.twig" is not defined. in Twig\Loader\ChainLoader->getCacheKey()

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: What theme suggestion are you trying to add exactly? For the paragraph type? For the paragraph in a certain panel? Is it about adding that from a custom module specifically? Or would it by OK to be added from your theme as well?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is coming from this code:

```
$theme_registry['page']['path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'example_ch_hero_panel') . '/templates';
```

The first array key, `page`, means you are working the `page` template. You've told the system to look for `page.html.twig` in your module's `/templates` directory. It's not finding it, so you get that error.

Remove that hook altogether, it's not the right way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, this is the explanation for the error the OP was seeing. This matches the code the OP was using. If then the OP got another error after removing the implementation of `_theme_registry_alter()`, that is a different matter. (It could simply be the OP needed to clear the cache, which could explain why the error comes from `Twig\Loader\ChainLoader->getCacheKey()`.)

Answer (score 0):

The following code is taken from a module that creates an accordion from a paragraph. (The module name has been changed.)

The *paragraph--accordion.html.twig* template file exists in mymodule/templates/paragraph.

```php
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $themes['paragraph__accordion'] = array(
    'template' => 'paragraph--accordion',
    'base hook' => 'paragraph',
    'path' => \Drupal::service('extension.list.module')->getPath('mymodule') . '/templates/paragraph'
  );

  return $themes;
}
```